# Is there a word with the meaning to mix "s" and "th" when pronounced?

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember I have met a word which means people cannot distinguish "th" from "s" when they speak but now I can't recollect it. So I need some help here. Does anyone know that word? P.S. It is a single word~

Comment: This isn't exactly what you asked but may help. ://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting

Comment: Is _lisp_ the word you are seeking?

Comment: I think the words _ceceo_ and _seseo_ reflect the difference in pronunciation of _c_ and _z_ in Spanish.  A _lisp_ is an inability to say a particular phoneme, but is not specific to his distinction and has nothing to do with ones perception of these two phoneme.

Comment: Correction: _Lisp_ is specific to the pronunciation of sibilants, but not to one's perception of the different sounds.

Comment: The word "lisp" means :pronounce "s" sounds as "th".I guess that's the word I am looking for. But is there a word that means:to pronounce "th" sounds as "s" or "f",just as the local people in HongKong do?

Comment: *[Shibboleth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth)* may also be of interest

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, the sigmatism is [lisping](http://medicine.academic.ru/30684/lisping)

[**parasigmatism**
    noun also para·sigmatismus \|parə+\
    Etymology: para- (I) + sigmatism or sigmatismus
    : inability to pronounce the sound of s with some other sound (as of f) being usually substituted for it](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/257951/parasigmatism)

> **SIGMATISM**, FRONTAL. A form of parasigmatism* character- ized by
>   substitution of surd th for s, and sonant th for z.
>   -A dictionary of terms dealing with disorders of ... . American Speech and Hearing Association

Comment: The word "lisp" means :pronounce "s" sounds as "th".I guess that's the word I am looking for. But is there a word that means:to pronounce "th" sounds as "s" or "f",just as the local people in HongKong do?

Comment: Paralalia: "Any speech defect; especially one in which one letter is habitually substituted for another."   Parathetacism  "par-ah-tha'-tah-sizm). A form of parala- lia* characterized by inability to pronounce surd or sonant th, or the substitution of other consonants, such as t or d, for th."